# figuring out how to do sql column aliases

Tags: mysql, database

I've been trying to figure out how to do column aliases with this query but I cannot seem to get it.

```
SELECT (customer.customer_id) as ID, (CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME) as name, (customer.address,customer.town,customer.post_code) as address, LOYALTY_CARD.POINTS 
FROM LOYALTY_CARD 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER 
ON LOYALTY_CARD.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID WHERE LOYALTY_CARD.POINTS > 70 ORDER BY LOYALTY_CARD.POINTS
```

The error I am receiving is `operand should contain 1 column`

Answer (score 1):

`(CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME) as name` is wrong. if you want to combine them, you need to concatenate them.

`concat(customer.first_name, ' ', customer.last_name) as name`

same for `(customer.address,customer.town,customer.post_code) as address`

`concat(customer.address, ' ', customer.town, ' ', customer.post_code) as address`